# Stop QListView from deleting entries on drag-drop

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistview

I have created a QListView with a QStringListModel.

```
listModel = new QStringListModel(ui->listView);
ui->listView->setModel(listModel);
ui->listView->setEditTriggers(QListView::NoEditTriggers);
ui->listView->setDragDropMode(QListView::InternalMove);
```

And I add items using:

```
void MainWindow::addItem(QString result)
{
    if (result == "")
        return;
    listModel->insertRow(listModel->rowCount());
    QModelIndex a = listModel->index(listModel->rowCount()-1);
    listModel->setData(a,result);
}
```

The problem is, when you drag an item in the list and try to move it to another position, it prefers to over-write the item you drag it to. I do not ever want an item to be deleted by a drag-drop action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation we get a bit of a hint of where to look for controlling overwrite behaviour in [QListView::dragDropOverwriteMode](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#dragDropOverwriteMode-prop):

> Note: This is not intended to prevent overwriting of items. The **model**'s implementation of **flags()** should do that by not returning **Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled**.

This tells us the model is the one that controls it. Then looking at the documentation for  [QStringListModel::flags(const QModelIndex & index) const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstringlistmodel.html#flags) we can see it does enable overwrite by default:

> Reimplemented from QAbstractItemModel::flags().
>   Returns the flags for the item with the given index.
>   Valid items are enabled, selectable, editable, drag enabled and **drop enabled.**

So in order to change this behaviour you will need to customize your model (i.e. derive from QStringListModel at minimum) and change the behaviour of the `flags(const QModelIndex & index) const` method to not return `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled`.

That should stop your entry from getting overwritten.

Comment: You don't have to subclass the model. If you use QStandardItem model, you can create QStandardItem, set appropriate flags and use this item in  ```setItemPrototype()```.

Comment: @Michal nailed it. Thanks!

Comment: This discussion is bit old but I just found it and it rocks ! Although, I had to disable `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled` only `if (index.isValid())`. Otherwise, I could not drop anything at all, not even in between items. Qt 5.9 here.